# Intermittent 500 Internal Server Errors in Redmine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine

Some users are getting 500 errors when logging in and when trying to browse certain pages or when the server's been idle for a while or visiting my controller page.

The production logs where 500 error occurred are the followings:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SELECT 
MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) FROM `settings`):
  app/models/setting.rb:231:in `check_cache'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:90:in `user_setup'

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-12-29 08:52:50 +0000
Processing by MyController#page as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) FROM `settings`):
  app/models/setting.rb:231:in `check_cache'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:90:in `user_setup'

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-12-29 08:52:56 +0000

Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rds-prod-db-xxxxx.c3uzu7me4rud.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (111)):

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 134ms (ActiveRecord: 69.2ms)
```

Second Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: UPDATE `issues` SET `issues`.`done_ratio` = 90, `issues`.`updated_on` = '2020-01-20 08:22:21', `issues`.`lock_version` = 49 WHERE `issues`.`id` = 328453 AND `issues`.`lock_version` = 48):
  app/models/issue.rb:210:in `create_or_update'
  app/models/issue.rb:1716:in `recalculate_attributes_for'
  app/models/issue.rb:1666:in `update_parent_attributes'
  app/models/issue.rb:210:in `create_or_update'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:558:in `block in save_issue_with_child_records'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:546:in `save_issue_with_child_records'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:168:in `update'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

Third Error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2020-02-02 09:07:22' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 289 AND `tokens`.`value` = 'a30e44e2ac37c8ba31eb383a409509c0d5fbb8be' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session' AND (created_on > '2020-02-01 09:07:22') AND (updated_on > '2020-02-01 09:07:22')):
  app/models/user.rb:445:in `verify_session_token'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:77:in `session_expired?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:67:in `session_expiration'

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-02 09:07:25 +0000
```

I saw an earlier in redmine forums topic having almost the same problem but have not found the solution yet.
Information:
Environment:

```
  Redmine version                3.4.4.stable
  Ruby version                   2.2.2-p95 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  4.2.8
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.7.14
  Git                            1.8.3.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_query_share            2.1.0
  redmine_agile                  1.4.5
  sidebar_hide                   0.0.7
```

Ruby Server: Puma
Puma_worker_killer config:

```
PumaWorkerKiller.config do |config|
    config.ram           = 4096 # mb
    config.frequency     = 60   # seconds
    config.percent_usage = 0.90
    config.rolling_restart_frequency = 10 * 3600 # 12 hours in seconds, or 12.hours if using Rails
    config.reaper_status_logs = true # setting this to false will not log lines like:
    # PumaWorkerKiller: Consuming 54.34765625 mb with master and 2 workers.

    config.pre_term = -> (worker) { puts "Worker #{worker.inspect} being killed" 
  Thread: 4-16
  }
  end
```

I am very new to ruby on rails and redmine. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried with the other version of Redmine? The problem seems with the connection with MySql.

Comment: @SantoshAryal This all happens in production environment. In development with this version or older or latest versions of redmine these error don't occur. I cannot change redmine version in production that easily, at least i don't have privileges.

Comment: @SantoshAryal Also, Do you know why the following error occurs in ROR? 
_ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server hasgone away )_

Comment: I've seen this issue before. One way it could happen is that the threads per worker exceed your db connection pool size. So, if you have more threads than the connection pool size, reduce them and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @myst any help?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this kind of issue in the past and found a solution by updating MySQL configuration (in my.cnf).
Add a line in your configuration file as follow:

```
[mysqld] 
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

Normally you don't need to restart your MySQL server.